# Set maven to use archiva repositories WITHOUT using activeByDefault?

Tags: maven, archiva

I am very close to finally having a working setup with archiva and maven.

The last thing that's really boggling me, is how to set up my internal and snapshot repositories - without using a profile which contains activeByDefault set to true.

I am using a SUPER super pom - a company-wide pom which contains distributionManagement information for releases. I was thinking that I could specify the repositories in this pom, and configure the authentication settings in settings.xml? Can I use repositories tag without a profile? There should be no "profile" for my internal and snapshot repositories, as they will never change...

What I'm trying to steer clear from, is using a "default" profile, which is active all the time. I hear activeByDefault is NOT a best practice and I don't intend to use it.

With that said, how should I go about doing this? My internal repo is a mirror of the maven central repo, so I would like to lock down my developers to ONLY use our internal artifact server. Remember - I do NOT want a profile with activeByDefault set to true. I cannot stress this enough! Should I use Maven mirrors? Should I "add" additional repositories?

If I take the repositories tag instead of the mirrors tag, will maven force builds to use ONLY my archiva settings, instead of the default maven central?

Or is what I seek to accomplish able to be done using only the mirrors tag in maven? I know how to configure repo credentials when using repositories tag, but not with mirrors. How is this done? Is providing credentials for anything in mirrors tags the same as for anything in repositories tags?

Am I missing something obvious? I've had it up to here with getting things up and running using maven. I know it will be worthwhile in the end, but it is surely causing me a ton of aggravation and resources seem to be sparse. Either that, or people are content using it however they please without regard to best-practices.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use your internal repo as a mirror of central you need to setup a mirror like this (in settings.xml):

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>my-internal-repo</id>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf> // use * for do mirror of all
        <name>Clinker Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://my-repo-host/my-repo-path</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

If `my-internal-repo` is protected you can set credentials:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>my-internal-repo</id>
        <username>youruser</username>
        <password>yourpassword</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Please, note the server id tag content should match the id of your mirror.

To use your `internal-snapshots` repository you must set a repository in your project POM, since the use of snapshots artifact should be controlled and clearly defined at the project level, not at the settings level:

```
<repository>
    <id>internal-snapshots</id>
    <url>http://your-repo-host/internal-snapshots-path</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

And finally, you must exclude `internal-snapshots` from the mirror:

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>my-internal-repo</id>
        <mirrorOf>central, !internal-snapshots</mirrorOf> // use * to do mirror of all
        <name>Clinker Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://my-repo-host/my-repo-path</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

and add a server (if it's protected):

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>my-internal-repo</id>
        <username>youruser</username>
        <password>yourpassword</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>internal-snapshots</id>
        <username>youruser</username>
        <password>yourpassword</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, such a clean way to do this. I can't stand to abuse maven profiles - this is an excellent workaround.

Comment: Does your configuration automatically download plugins from the maven central repo as well, or must I add <pluginManagement> tags somewhere too? If so, how do I set them up?

Comment: The mirror should work for plugins too. No more configuration is required.